# Auto-layout issue with stack view and label's font size

Tags: xcode, autolayout, storyboard, uilabel, uistackview

I really wanted to figure this out by myself but it's been 3 hours now and I don't think this kind of problem is worth half that amount of time so here I am seeking for help.

This is an `auto-layout problem` so I will try my best to illustrate it correctly.

I have a `stack view` containing two `labels` (`O` and `_` in the storyboard). The problem is that I can't fix the size of the `stack view` to have the `label's font size` `auto-shrink` on smaller screens and have them displayed correctly on bigger screens at the same time...

**Works best on iPhone 5s:**

Storyboard =

[image: iphone5s storyboard]
[image]

Constraints =

[image]

Simulator =

[image]

iPhone 8 result =

[image]

**Works best on iPhone 8, 8+ and bigger screens:**

Storyboard =

[image]

Constraints =

[image]

Simulator =

[image]

iPhone 5s and smaller screens result =

[image]

I guess this is the `StackView` that makes things harder than they should be.. it would be great that the `labels` inside the `stack view` don't have a fixed size. What can I do?

Comment: What constraints do you have on your stack view?

Comment: Hi Linus, the constraints for the `stack view` are displayed in the screenshots.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for the stack view's trailing constraint. The only one I can see is `trailing = Stack View.trailing - 15`. Is the left part of the equation supposed to be the superview?

Comment: Indeed it is. This is what allows the `auto-shrink` to work, but the constraint also gives the `labels` inside the `stack view` a fixed size that mess the arrangement on bigger screens when there is not enough text to fill all the space.

Comment: Should I give up and print everything in a single label?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the relationship of the trailing constraint `trailing = Stack View.trailing - 15` from `Equal` to `Greater than or equal`.

For example you need: `trailing >= Stack View.trailing + 15`

In that way the trailing part of the stack view will have 15 points distance to the trailing edge of the superview so will auto shrink if there is no enough space. At the same time if there is a lot of space the labels will not be expanded because each label will hug its content.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nested stackViews (StackView inside StackView inside StackView etc.) the top StackView has to have top and bottom constraints, but the bottom has to be of kind "greater than" (e.g. ">= 1").

Without both constraints the height is often miscalculated and same happens if there is no "space to breath" for the layout process, because the constraints are set to tight.